Limit at minus infinity of the derivative of an strictly increasing function
Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is strictly increasing and $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. The derivative $f'$ is also strictly increasing and $f'(x)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Therefore we have that
$$
     \lim_{x \to -\infty} f'(x) = c \geq 0,
$$
as $f'$ is stricly incresing and bounded from below. My question is if it follows that $c=0$?
My intuition says that yes because if not, then at some point $f(x)$ must be negative reaching a contradiction.

Yes. For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
0 \leq c \leq \int_x^{x + 1} f'(t)\; dt = f(x + 1) - f(x).
$$
Now, since $\lim\limits_{x \to - \infty} f(x) = d$ exists as it is bounded below and increasing, we have that $\lim\limits_{x \to - \infty} f(x +1) - f(x) = d -d = 0$, showing that $c = 0$.
